# How do you change which program to debug in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I searched and could not find anyone else with this issue. I have several projects, and want to debug specific ones as I wish. However, it keeps making me only debug the same program unless I unload it, which seems wrong. I feel there has to be some way to quickly specify which program I want to debug.

I attached a screenshot and added red lines around the part where it says what it's debugging and the programs I wish to debug. It wants to debug uart.cpp, but I want to debug open_device.cpp.

How can I do this without unloading uart.cpp? I appreciate any help!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiwvQ.png)

Comment: Does the answer can help you, if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In Solution Explorer, right click on the project and choose "Set as Startup Project"

Additionally, you can start multiple projects by using the context menu on the solution.

In Solution Explorer, right click on the solution and choose "Set Startup Projects"

Comment: Cheers, happy debugging.